# Remove mirrored duplicate strings in list python?

Tags: python

What is an efficient python algorithm to remove all mirrored text duplicates in a list where the items are in the format as below?

```
ExList = [' dutch italian english', ' italian english dutch', ' dutch italian german', ' dutch german italian' ]
```

Required result: `[' dutch english italian ', 'dutch german italian' ]`

Comment: This sounds like homework in which case you should provide what you've tried

Comment: What have you tried? You can split in spaces, sort them and convert them to tuples for use in a set comprehension, and then convert back to a list of strings. That won't preserve original order, if that's a requirement. I can provide an example when I get back to my machine.

Comment: @Ian Quah I assure you that is not the case, I have tried sorting each item in alphabetical order and removing duplicate strings to no avail. I am looking for a more efficient algorithm as my lists are much larger in my project.

Comment: @Maus an example with python syntax will be much appreciated, bless you.

Comment: Can you provide the code you used to attempt to solve the problem? It's probably more useful for us to point to your mistake rather than just provide an answer.

Comment: `'dutch english italian'` isn't in the original list.

Comment: that result is also a SyntaxError -- it looks like it's missing a quote mark.

Comment: @Peter Wood Right you are, that output would be given if each word in the list was sorted first

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solution uses the [set](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#set-types-set-frozenset) datastructure and focuses on producing compact code, mostly with list/set/generator comprehenstions. If this is a homework task for a beginner course and you just copy the result, it will be very obvious that you did not write the code yourself. Try to follow the thought process and reproduce the results yourself.

---

1) split each element at `" "` (space)

```
for item in ExList:
    splitted = item.split(" ")
```

2) remove now empty elements due to superfluous spaces in the input. This can be done in 1 line with the step above (empty strings are "falsy") using a *list comprehenstion*:

```
for item in ExList:
    splitted = [lang for lang in item.split(" ") if lang]
```

3) Put the result in a set, which by definition disregards order and ignores duplicates. For this step we primarily need the property of unordered identity, meaning `set([1, 2]) == set([2, 1])`. This can be combined with the line above using a *generator comprehension*:

```
for item in ExList:
    itemSet = set(lang for lang in item.split(" ") if lang)
```

Now, within that loop, put all those sets of languages into another set. This time, because all the item sets with the same items in any order are considered equal, the outer set will automatically disregard any duplicates. To be able to put the item set into another set, it needs to be immutable (because mutability might cause a change in identity), which is called a `frozenset` in python. The code looks like this:

```
ExList = [' dutch italian english', ' italian english dutch', ' dutch italian german', ' dutch german italian' ]

result = set()
for item in ExList:
    result.add(frozenset(lang for lang in item.split(" ") if lang))
```

Or, as a *set comprehension* on one line:

```
result = {frozenset(lang for lang in item.split(" ") if lang) for item in ExList}
```

The result is as follows:

```
>>> print(result)
{frozenset({'italian', 'dutch', 'german'}), frozenset({'italian', 'dutch', 'english'})}
```

you can turn that back into lists if the set print output looks confusing to you

```
>>> print([list(itemSet) for itemSet in result])
[['italian', 'dutch', 'german'], ['italian', 'dutch', 'english']]
```

Comment: Thank you x100 Felk for this well explained answer, it means a lot to me and will hopefully will help users who have a similar question in the future. I understand that the way my question is formulated gives the impression that it is homework hence the down votes, for the record I'm currently in HS and am doing this for a personal project.

Answer (score 0):

This may work for you:

```
def unique_list(s):
    x = set([tuple(sorted(s.split())) for s in ExList])
    return [" ".join(s) for s in x]

print(unique_list(ExList)
```

Answer (score 0):

This might not be the most efficient solution, but hope it will be of some help.

Using the property that keys of dictionary are unique.

```
m_dict = {}

for a in ExList:
    b = a.split()
    b.sort()
    m_dict[' '.join(b)] = None

print m_dict.keys()
```

Comment: Why not use a `set`?

Comment: `list({' '.join(a.split().sort()) for a in ExList})`

Comment: @PeterWood it required more iterations to get back the original list item. Lists cannot be hashed so the set won't work here directly, isn't it?

Comment: Where would you be trying to `hash` a `list`? the `list` is joined into a `str`, which is immutable and can be hashed.